# $_SESSION Not working after X amount of page views

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, conditional-tags, session

I've written up a simple function that's output into header.php, which displays the login/register modal upon so many views in this case I've set it at 4, however its firing on the first view of my listings CPT. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the function:

```
function ct_display_login_register_after_x_views() {

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
        $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'] + 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
    }

    if($_SESSION['views'] >= 4 && !is_user_logged_in() && is_singular('listings') ) {
        $output = '<script>';
            $output .= 'jQuery(window).load(function() {';
                $output .= "jQuery('#overlay').addClass('open');";
                $output .= "jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);";
                $output .= 'return false;';
            $output .= '});';
        $output .= '</script>';

        $output .= '<style>';
            $output .= '#modal .close { display: none;}';
        $output .= '</style>';

        echo $output;

    }
}
```

Then the output in header.php

```
<?php ct_display_login_register_after_x_views(); ?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind this system will never work with caching, your site will never be capable of high traffic situations, it'll also fail on some hosts, e.g. a site running on WP Engine will never work with this code. Also note that your session counting code runs on every page, not just listings. Would it not be better to do this 100% on the client side in JS?

Comment: Gotcha, what would be the best way to do this with pure JS? Any examples that sounds like a much better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Use local storage in JS or equivalent to store the number of times a listing has been viewed. This way you only need to figure out if you're on a listings page in JS, which is trivial if you've built your theme correctly ( and a very good question to ask as a new question )

Comment: Opened another thread for a JS based version https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288286/js-cookie-for-displaying-modal-after-x-pageviews again any help is greatly appreciated!